# Iron Butterfly Relationship with Butterfly

Tags: options

I'm reading Natenburg's Options book, and I'm not understanding why "Buying a traditional butterfly is equivalent to selling an iron butterfly," because later in the text Natenburg says that "If we sell the June 95 / 100 / 105 iron butterfly we will take in some amount between zero and 5.00. We also hope that the underlying will finish at 100, in which case all the options will be worthless and we will profit by the amount of the original sale," but if selling/shorting the iron butterfly is longing the original butterfly, why don't we have the same payoff?

And why must the prices of a butterfly and iron butterfly must add up to the difference in exercise prices?

Could someone explain and clarify the reasoning? Thanks!

Like the book uses the example of the following position:

+1 June 95 put

−1 June 100 call

−1 June 100 put

+1 June 105 call

and compares it with a usual long 95/100/105 butterfly. At expiration, if the underlying is worth $102, the butterfly is worth \$3, but the position given (the short iron butterfly) is worth -\$2.

Comment: They do have the same payoff diagram, don't they (please draw the diagrams).

Comment: @nbbo2 my confusion though is that if longing butterfly == shorting iron butterfly, why does staying put make money for the long butterfly (+5), but the options are worthless for the iron?